# For loop not reading last character in String

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a basic key cipher, but I'm having an issue with the for loop not reading the last character:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BasicEncrypt.encrypt("abcdef", 1);}

public class BasicEncrypt {

    public static String encrypt(String text, int rule) {

        String code = "";
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < text.length() -1; i++) {
            if ((text.charAt(i) + rule) > 255) {
                code = code + (char) (text.charAt(i) + rule - 255);
            } else if (text.charAt(i) + rule <= 255) {
                code = code + text.charAt(i) + rule);
            }
        }

        return code;
    }
}
```

The code returns everything but the last character. If the input string is one character ('a') the return is empty.

I change the loop to the following and get an index out of bounds error (which ofc makes sense):

```
        for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
```

I realize this is a very basic question but I could not find my answer on here after about an hour of searching.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `for` loop is `for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)`. And you need to change

```
} else if (text.charAt(i) + rule <= 255) {
    code = code + text.charAt(i + rule);
}
```

to

```
} else if (text.charAt(i) + rule <= 255) {
    code = code + text.charAt(i) + rule;
}
```

After your corrections, you moved the mistake you made once and did the same mistake again. **Four times**. This

```
if (text.charAt(i + rule) > 255) {
    code = code + (char) (text.charAt(i + rule) - 255);
} else if (text.charAt(i + rule) <= 255) {
    code = code + text.charAt(i + rule);
}
```

Is wrong. `i + rule` is always going to give you an out of bounds exception when `rule` is greater than `0` because `i` is the range of all valid indices in `text`.

```
if (text.charAt(i) + rule > 255) {
    code = code + (char) (text.charAt(i) + rule - 255);
} else if (text.charAt(i) + rule <= 255) {
    code = code + text.charAt(i) + rule;
}
```

Just make your life simpler like

```
char ch = text.charAt(i);
if (ch + rule > 255) {
    code += ch + rule - 255;
} else {
    code += ch + rule;
}
```

Comment: After these corrections I am still receiving "Index 6 out of bounds for length 6" - please check out revised question.

Comment: Ah, whoops, your corrections were correct. I had to add (char) but I accidentally did the opposite of what you recommended at first. Thanks!

Comment: I misread your answer, didn't expect you to reply so fast before I corrected myself!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate on a string called text, you must start from 0 to text.length -1, in this case your condition will be like : i <= text.length
otherwise if you use just "<" , the last index doesn't count, and it should be like this : for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)